# Checking user input with string array

Tags: c++, string, input

```
string code[4] = {"G", "O", "B", "R"};
string colorPegs[6] = {"R", "B", "Y", "G", "O", "B"};
string userGuess;

    getline(cin,userGuess);
```

Those are the important lines of code in my question.

The user will input 4 letters, for example "BBYG"

How can I make a for loop that checks the first char of user input with the first char of code, and sees if it matches?

for example:

string code is GOBR

user inputs BBBR. In user input, only one letter matches the code, which is the third B, how can I check for this with a for loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you want to check for a complete match?  Or count the number of characters that match?  Or find the index of the first match?  Can you edit your question to provide more information?

Comment: To check if the first letter is in an Array you can use Array.contains. Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015(v=vs.100).ASPXchar firstletter = userGuess[0];

Comment: All your "strings" in the first two lines consist of only a single character. Consider using real characters to simplify the task.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code assuming you want to find a match if they are at the same position :

```
for(int i = 0; i < code.length(); ++i)
{
    if(code[i] == user[i]) return true;    // Match found here.
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string code{"GOBR"};
    std::string input;

    std::cin >> input;

    auto match = [&] (char c)
    {
        return std::find(code.begin(), code.end(), c) != code.end();
    };

    if (std::any_of(input.begin(), input.end(), match))
    {
        // match
    }
}
```